# cmath function implementation with RPN calculator

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with implementing cmath functions within an RPN calc. 
I am noticing different behaviours of my calls. **If I have pow(y,x)** in the POW statement I receive 0.5 as my answer from the expression: 
**2 1 arctan cos pow (correct).. 
But then using the same code if I enter: 
3 recip 8 pow I receive 0 (incorrect)..**

**However, If I switch the y and x in the pow() call (pow(x,y))** and enter:
**2 1 arctan cos pow I receive 0.9 (incorrect)
and if I enter: 
3 recip 8 pow I receive 2 (correct)..**

I have tried `atan(stack.peek());` but that returns 0 with `pow(y,x)` and 1 with `pow(x,y);`

My logic must be wrong somewhere I am just unsure.. Thankyou

**stack.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    HPStack stack;
    string line;

    while(getline(cin,line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string token;
        while(ss >> token){
            if(isdigit(token[0])){
                stack.push(atof(token.data()));
            } else if (token == "+"){
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(y+x);
            } else if (token == "-"){
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(y-x);
            } else if (token == "/"){
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(y/x);
            } else if (token == "*"){
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(y*x);
            } else if (token == "COS"){
                stack.push(cos(stack.peek()));
            } else if (token == "ARCTAN"){
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(atan2(x,y));
            else if (token == "RECIP"){
                double x = stack.peek();
                double y = stack.peek();
                double recip = 1/y;
                stack.push(recip);
            } else if (token == "POW"){
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                double sum = pow(y,x);
                double answer = (int)(sum*10.0)/10.0;
                stack.push(answer);
            } 
        }
        cout << stack.peek() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

HPStack.h

```
#ifndef HPSTACK_H_
#define HPSTACK_H_

class HPStack {
    public:
        void push(double value);
        double pop();
        double peek();
    private:
        double x=0.0,y=0.0,z=0.0,t=0.0;
};

#endif
```

HPStack.cpp

```
#include "HPStack.h"

void HPStack::push(double value){
    t = z;
    z = y;
    y = x;
    x = value;
}

double HPStack::pop(){
    double out; 
    out = x;
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = t;
    return out;
}

double HPStack::peek(){
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Your cos and recip implementations look wrong. And why limit your stack to 4 elements? C++ has a standard stack class...

Comment: Also think about what happens if you try to pop from an empty stack.

Comment: Sounds like the best time to learn to use a debugger - to step through the program and watch the variables.